# Error: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'OFFSET' RAZOR MVC WEBMATRIX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Buenas tengo el siguiente error y no se donde se estara originado

Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'OFFSET'.
Uso no válido de la opción NEXT en la instrucción FETCH.

eh intentado de todo pero no logro solucionar el problema, acá les dejo el codigo

```
   string searchText = Request["srch"] ?? "";
string ipp = Request["ipp"] ?? "5";
string pg = Request["pg"] ?? "0";
int pgNumber = 1;
int.TryParse(pg, out pgNumber);
if (pgNumber < 0)
{
    pgNumber = -pgNumber;

}
else if (pgNumber == 0)
{
    pgNumber = 1;
}

string pmin = Request["pmin"];
string pmax = Request["pmax"];
float preciomin = -1f, preciomax = -1f;

float.TryParse(pmin, out preciomin);
if (preciomin < 0)
{
    preciomin = -preciomin;

}
else if (preciomin == 0)
{
    preciomin = -1;
}

float.TryParse(pmax, out preciomax);
if (preciomax < 0)
{
    preciomax = -preciomax;

}
else if (preciomax == 0)
{
    preciomax = -1;
}

string categoria = Request["cat"];

if (categoria == String.Empty)
{
    categoria = null;
}

string categoriaHija = Request["cath"];

if (categoriaHija == String.Empty)
{
    categoriaHija = null;
}

string provincia = Request["prov"];

if (provincia == String.Empty)
{
    provincia = null;
}

string ciudad = Request["ciud"];

if (ciudad == String.Empty)
{
    ciudad = null;
}

int itemsPP = 5;
int.TryParse(ipp, out itemsPP);
if (itemsPP < 0)
{
    itemsPP = -itemsPP;
}
else if (itemsPP == 0)
{
    itemsPP = 5;
}


var db = Database.Open("Restate1320");

searchText = searchText.Replace(',', ' ').Replace('.', ' ').Replace("'", "''");
string[] spl = searchText.Split(' ');
System.Text.StringBuilder query = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
int limit = spl.Length;
string part;
string not = string.Empty;
int order = 1;
string condicionPrecio;

if(preciomin == -1f && preciomax == -1f)
{
    condicionPrecio = string.Empty;
}
else if (preciomin == -1f && preciomax != -1f)
{
    condicionPrecio = string.Format("Precio < {0} AND ", preciomax);
}
else if (preciomin != -1f && preciomax == -1f)
{
    condicionPrecio = string.Format("Precio > {0} AND ", preciomin);
}
else
{
    condicionPrecio = string.Format("Precio BETWEEN {0} AND {1} AND ", preciomin, preciomax);
}

while (limit > 0)
{
    part = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        part += spl[i] + " ";
    }
    part = part.Remove(part.Length - 1);

    query.AppendFormat("SELECT *, {0} AS Orden FROM VArticulos WHERE {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} (Titulo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI LIKE '%{6}%' OR Descripcion COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI LIKE '%{6}%') {7} UNION ", order++, categoria != null ? string.Format("Categoria = {0} AND ", categoria) : "", provincia != null ? string.Format("IdProvincia = {0} AND ", provincia) : "", ciudad != null ? string.Format("IdCiudad = {0} AND ", ciudad) : "", condicionPrecio, categoriaHija != null ? string.Format("UsuarioP = {0} AND ", categoriaHija) : "", part, not);
    not += string.Format("AND NOT (Titulo LIKE '%{0}%' OR Descripcion LIKE '%{0}%') ", part);
    limit--;
}
query = query.Remove(query.Length - 6, 5);
string qt = query.ToString();
var nresults = db.QueryValue(string.Format("SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM ({0}) AS Result", qt));
while ((pgNumber - 1) * itemsPP > nresults)
{
    pgNumber--;
}

string q = string.Format("SELECT * FROM ({0}) AS Result ORDER BY Orden OFFSET {1} ROWS FETCH NEXT {2} ROWS ONLY", qt, (pgNumber - 1) * itemsPP, itemsPP);
var result = db.Query(q);
pgNumber.ToString();

db.Close();
```

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado esta línea en tu SQL Server? string q = string.Format("SELECT * FROM ({0}) AS Result ORDER BY Orden OFFSET {1} ROWS FETCH NEXT {2} ROWS ONLY", qt, (pgNumber - 1) * itemsPP, itemsPP);

Comment: Eliminare esta entrada ya que es un error de compatibilidad en SQL Server... Perdon!"